# Set up Neovim integration in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim

Currently a (neo)vim user, I read that VS Code supports neovim backend integration, but after searching I cannot find how to set it up.

How to set up neovim integration in VS Code?

I use both linux and windows so if there are some OS specifity you could mention it.

Comment: I believe the integration you read about was referring the neovim integration in VSCodeVim: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#neovim-integration

Comment: This one uses a real instance of neovim as editor back-end: https://github.com/asvetliakov/vscode-neovim